# Default translations for Mac OS X applications

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I want to localize my Mac app in a couple of different languages. I added more languages in the project info tab, which created a .strings-file for each language with the English strings in there. But there are a lot of default entries in the menubar like File, Edit, Print, etc. which I don't want to translate by myself. Is there a way to just use the default translation for these entries and only translate my custom strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not automatic, but [Apple provides "glossaries"](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=glossar) of the strings from OS X that are translated to other languages. These are intended to be used with [AppleGlot](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=appleglot), which is a crufty old tool for localizing. Using those together, you can get a jump-start on your translations.